# Doubts about string

Tags: python-3.x, string

So, I'm doing an exercise using python, and I tried to use the terminal to do step by step to understand what's happening but I didn't.

I want to understand mainly why the conditional return just the index 0.
Looking `'casino' in [Casinoville].lower()` isn't the same thing?

## Exercise:

- Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
  Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents containing the keyword.

### Exercise solution

```
def word_search(documents, keyword):
    indices = [] 
    for i, doc in enumerate(documents):

        tokens = doc.split()
        normalized = [token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in tokens]

        if keyword.lower() in normalized:
            indices.append(i)
    return indices
```

### My solution

```
def word_search(documents, keyword):
    return [i for i, word in enumerate(doc_list) if keyword.lower() in word.rstrip('.,').lower()]
```

### Run

```
>>> doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
```

#### Expected output

```
>>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
>>> [0]
```

#### Actual output

```
>>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
>>> [0, 2]
```

Comment: Hint: type these two lines into an interpreter: `'casino' in 'casinoville'` and `'casino' in ['casinoville']`. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @glibdud is about that I'm confused why `'casino' in 'casinoville'` returns `True` and `'casino' in ['casinoville']` return `False`,  why this happening?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) is always a good place to start when you're trying to figure out how language features work. See the first two paragraphs of the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to understand the difference.

The "result" function can be written with list-comprehension:

```
def word_search(documents, keyword):
    return [i for i, word in enumerate(documents) 
                if keyword.lower() in 
                    [token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in word.split()]]
```

The problem happens with the string : `"Casinoville"` at index `2`.

See the output:

```
print([token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in doc_list[2].split()])
# ['casinoville']
```

And here is the matter: you try to ckeck **if a word is in the list**. The answer is `True` only if all the string matches (this is the expected output).

However, in your solution, you only check if a word contains a substring. In this case, the condition `in` is on the `string` itself and not the `list`.

See it:

```
# On the list : 
print('casino' in [token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in doc_list[2].split()])
# False

# On the string:
print('casino' in [token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in doc_list[2].split()][0])
# True
```

As result, in the first case, `"Casinoville"` isn't included while it is in the second one.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Glad to help you ! Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is "Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents containing the keyword".

you need to consider word only.

In "Casinoville" case, word "casino" is not in, since this case only have word "Casinoville".

Comment: Yes sure, but what I want to understand is that in **exercise solution** the conditional `if keyword.lower() in normalized:` return `False` in the last index, how? Because in my solution that returns `True` and makes me confused.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `in` operator, the result depends on the type of object on the right hand side. When it's a list (or most other kinds of containers), you get an exact membership test. So `'casino' in ['casino']` is `True`, but `'casino' in ['casinoville']` is `False` because the strings are not equal.

When the right hand side of `is` is a string though, it does something different. Rather than looking for an exact match against a single character (which is what strings contain if you think of them as sequences), it does a substring match. So `'casino' in 'casinoville'` is `True`, as would be `casino in 'montecasino'` or `'casino' in 'foocasinobar'` (it's not just prefixes that are checked).

For your problem, you want exact matches to whole words only. The reference solution uses `str.split` to separate words (the with no argument it splits on any kind of whitespace). It then cleans up the words a bit (stripping off punctuation marks), then does an `in` match against the list of strings.

Your code never splits the strings you are passed. So when you do an `in` test, you're doing a substring match on the whole document, and you'll get false positives when you match part of a larger word.